Framer motion background color change from left to right
I saw this effect on the following website (link below), and I tried to replicate it using framer motion (React.js), but it didn't work.
The effect is, when the user hover on the card, the background changes color from white to the primary color of the website. But the color change is directional, it moves from left to right (x: 0 to x:100). I tried it with hover and it changes, but the change happens on the whole card at once (like a normal hover). I can't figure out how they made it directional. I'm using framer motion for React.js
Any help will be appreciated.. thanks in advance...
This is the link to page that contains the card, you will find it in the "Trending" section:
https://ukf.com/read/
This is my code:
import { FC } from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { Stack, Typography, Divider, Button } from "@mui/material";


const NewsCard: FC = () => {
    return (
        <motion.div
            whileHover={{
                // backgroundColor: ["var(--dark-bg)", "var(--secondary)"]
                // background: "linear-gradient(to right, var(--dark-bg) 0%, var(--secondary) 100%)",
                // backgroundColor: "var(--secondary)",
                // backgroundSize: "250%"
            }}
            transition={{
                duration: 0.3,
                ease: "easeIn"
            }}
            style={{
                // height: "90%",
                // height: "100%",
                // border: "1px solid var(--secondary)",
                backgroundColor: "var(--dark-bg)"
                // background: "linear-gradient(to right, var(--dark-bg) 0%, var(--secondary) 100%)"
            }}
        >
            <Stack
                direction="row"
                justifyContent="space-between"
                alignItems="center"
            >
                <Stack direction="row" alignItems="center">
                    <Typography variant="overline">
                        Tag1
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="overline">
                        Tag2
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="overline">
                        Tag3
                    </Typography>
                </Stack>
                <Typography variant="overline">
                    {/* <time dateTime={ article.created_at!.toString() }>
                        { dayjs(article.created_at).format("DD MMM YYYY") }
                    </time> */}
                    11/02/2024
                </Typography>
            </Stack>
            <Divider sx={{ borderColor: "secondary.main" }} />
            <Stack justifyContent="space-between"
                style={{
                    // height: "93%"
                    // display: "grid",
                    // gridTemplateRows: "auto 1fr"
                }}
            >
                <Stack>
                    <Typography variant="h4">
                        Ut sapiente ut nemo dicta et rem rerum ratione beatae. Ut sapiente ut nemo dicta et rem rerum ratione beatae.
                    </Typography>
                    <Stack spacing={1} direction="row">
                        <div style={{ width: "20px", height: "20px", backgroundColor: "red" }} />
                        <Typography>by</Typography>
                        <Typography>Hazem Saeed</Typography>
                    </Stack>
                </Stack>

                <Stack sx={{ mt: "7vh !important" }}>
                    <Typography
                        sx={{
                            width: "95%",
                            height: "10vh",
                            textOverflow: "ellipsis",
                            // whiteSpace: "nowrap",
                            overflow: "hidden"
                        }}
                    >
                        Ipsam quam et non ut. Reprehenderit unde sunt minus. Sit quia similique sunt quam. Velit neque voluptatem quod. Et qui quam sint cupiditate sunt repellendus unde est temporibus.
                    </Typography>
                    <Stack alignItems="flex-end">
                        <Button
                            variant="outlined"
                            size="small"
                            sx={{ width: "130px" }}
                        >
                            read more
                        </Button>
                    </Stack>
                </Stack>
            </Stack>
        </motion.div>
    );
};

export default NewsCard;


It looks as though the idea of using a linear-gradient is already in  your code (albeit commented out currently).
Here's a simple, pure CSS, example of gradually increasing the size of that background on hover.
Note that setting background-repeat to no-repeat is necessary, otherwise the linear-gradient will repeat and fill the space.


<style>
  div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    --bg: magenta;
    background-image: linear-gradient(var(--bg), var(--bg));
    background-size: 0 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transition: background-size 1s linear;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  
  div:hover {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
</style>
<div>Hover me</div>




Thank you so much for your solution. But I only have one problem, the exit animation (while using framer motion) is abrupt; meaning it's not linear as the enter animation.
Do you have any idea on how to solve this?
Thanks again...

I have no idea about framer motion I’m afraid. Do you have to use that rather than plain CSS?

No, I don't have to. But I have to learn framer motion library in order to create complex animations. That's why this would be a great training for it.
Thanks, you've been a great help, truly..
